Derive a tuple type from an array of typed objects
If I have a generic parameter   T extends SomeObjectWithGenericParameter<unknown> I want to derive a type that is an array with those unknown types inferred
eg.
type SomeObjectWithGenericParameter<T> = {
  value: T; 
}

type ExtractDataAsArray<T extends Array<SomeObjectWithGenericParameter<unknown>>> = unknown;  // implementation here 


type TypedArray = [a: string, b:  number]; 
type A = ExtractDataAsArray<[{value: string}, {value: number}]>; // Should be equivalent to TypedArray

Here's the more practical example of what I'm trying to do:
type LoadingPayload<T> = {
  data:T, 
  isSuccess: true,
  isLoading: false, 
} | {
  data: null, 
  isSuccess: false, 
  isLoading: true, 
}

type ExtractDataTypes<T extends Array<LoadingPayload<unknown>>> = unknown; // implementation here 

function myFunction<T extends Array<LoadingPayload<unknown>>> (dataPayloads: T, processData: (data: ExtractDataTypes<T>) => void) {

}

const d1 : LoadingPayload<string> = {
  isLoading: true,
  isSuccess: false, 
  data: null, 
}; 

const d2 : LoadingPayload<number> = {
  isLoading: false, 
  isSuccess: true, 
  data: 2, 
}

myFunction([d1,d2], (data) => {
    
  const a: string = data[0]; // should be string 
  const b: number = data[1]; // should be number
  const c: never = data[2]; // should be never 

}); 


How do I implement that ExtractDataTypes type?
Here's my attempt:
type ExtractDataTypes<T extends Array<LoadingPayload<unknown>>> = {
  [K in keyof T ] : T[K] extends LoadingPayload<infer U> ? U : never; 
}

But this doesn't work - in the example use case we data is an Array<number>

Please do correct me if I've got any of my terminology wrong here.

Here's the correct answer:
type ExtractDataTypes<T extends Array<LoadingPayload<unknown>>> = {
  [K in keyof T ] : (T[K] & {isSuccess: true})["data"] extends infer U ? U: never; 
}

I was on the right track with the infer.
We create a mapped typed and use the indexed access type of compare against the inferred type:
type ExtractDataTypes<T extends Array<LoadingPayload<unknown>>> = {
  [K in keyof T ] : (T[K])["data"] extends infer U ? U: never; 
}

//type A = [a: null, b: number | null]
type A = ExtractDataTypes<[a: LoadingPayload<null>, b: LoadingPayload<number>]>


Now the problem with this is that TypeScript knows that the value at data can still be null (when it's loading). To solve we just add a {isSuccess: true} intersection.
type ExtractDataTypes<T extends Array<LoadingPayload<unknown>>> = {
  [K in keyof T ] : (T[K] & {isSuccess: true})["data"] extends infer U ? U: never; 
}

//type A = [a: null, b: number]
type A = ExtractDataTypes<[a: LoadingPayload<null>, b: LoadingPayload<number>]>


In this particular case we can do it this way, it's a bit imperfect:
type ExtractDataTypes<T extends Array<LoadingPayload<unknown>>> = {
  [K in keyof T ] : Exclude<T[K]['data'], null> extends never ? null :  Exclude<T[K]['data'], null>; 
}

Step 1 - Reconstruct the array type
type ExtractDataTypes<T extends Array<LoadingPayload<unknown>>> = {
  [K in keyof T ] : K[T]
}

does nothing we're just reconstructing our original array type.
//type A = [a: LoadingPayload<string>, b: LoadingPayload<number>]
type A = ExtractDataTypes<[a: LoadingPayload<string>, b: LoadingPayload<number>]>; 

Step 2 - Indexed access type
We can get at the data type by adding an indexed access type
type ExtractDataTypes<T extends Array<LoadingPayload<unknown>>> = {
  [K in keyof T ] : K[T]["data"] // <-- add ["data"] 
}

//type A = [a: string | null, b: number | null]
type A = ExtractDataTypes<[a: LoadingPayload<string>, b: LoadingPayload<number>]>; 

Step 3 - Exclude the nulls
Now we can just exclude the nulls from the result
type ExtractDataTypes<T extends Array<LoadingPayload<unknown>>> = {
  [K in keyof T ] : Exclude<T[K]['data'], null>; 
}
//type A = [a: string, b: number]
type A = ExtractDataTypes<[a: LoadingPayload<string>, b: LoadingPayload<number>]>; 

Problem - nulls
The problem with this if any of your data types are null, you'll get a never
type ExtractDataTypes<T extends Array<LoadingPayload<unknown>>> = {
  [K in keyof T ] : Exclude<T[K]['data'], null>; 
}


// type A = [a: never, b: number]
type A = ExtractDataTypes<[a: LoadingPayload<null>, b: LoadingPayload<number>]>; 

Step 4 - check for nevers
We actually can then do a conditional check to see if the the type's a never and turn it back into a null;
type ExtractDataTypes<T extends Array<LoadingPayload<unknown>>> = {
  [K in keyof T ] : Exclude<T[K]['data'], null> extends never ? null :  Exclude<T[K]['data'], null>; 
}

// type A = [a: null, b: number]
type A = ExtractDataTypes<[a: LoadingPayload<null>, b: LoadingPayload<number>]>; 

But the problem with this is that if you had a type that was a never it would be incorrectly turned back into a null.
I'm sure there's a better way to do this.
